# Python argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter with line wrap

Tags: python, argparse

In my argument parsing code I need to use `argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter` but I would also like to have the lines automatically wrapped at a fixed width in the same way as with the default formatter.

Is there any elegant way how to combine these two behaviors?

Comment: Maybe `textwrpa` can help you?:https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html

Comment: Sounds like you need your own custom formatter.  Look at the code for `RawTextHelpFormatter`.  Note the method that it modifies.  Look where that method is used in the regular `HelpFormatter`.

Comment: `argparse` does import `textwrap`, and uses it to `split_lines`.  `RawTextHelpFormatter` changes `split_lines`, bypassing `textwrap`.  Maybe you can implement a partial bypass.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue12806 is a bug/issue that proposes a hybrid formatter, one that allows features like bullet points and paragraphs, but also wraps.  It probably won't be added to `argparse` but the suggested changes can be added to your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Write Custom RawTextHelpFormatter

You can just write your own `RawTextHelpFormatter`. The `RawTextHelpFormatter` has only differences in the method `_fill_text` and `_split_lines` from the `ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` so just overwrite the `_spilt_lines_` method fixes this issue with the line wrap.

```
import argparse
import textwrap as _textwrap

class LineWrapRawTextHelpFormatter(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        text = self._whitespace_matcher.sub(' ', text).strip()
        return _textwrap.wrap(text, width)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='PROG',
    formatter_class=LineWrapRawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=int, default=42, help="FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an u")
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='*', default=[1, 2, 3], help="BAR! FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.")
parser.print_help()
```

## Output

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo FOO] [bar [bar ...]]

positional arguments:
  bar         BAR! FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
              standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an u
```

As you see the line is automatically wrapped. If you want to adjust the width, you can hardcode the width at `_textwrap.wrap(text, width)` (its the width only of the Part starting with `FOO! Lorem`) in the `_spilit_lines` method or use `_os.environ['COLUMNS']` (Thats the width of the complete help text).

**Code with columns=40**

```
import os
os.environ['COLUMNS'] = "40"
```

**Output**

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo FOO]
            [bar [bar ...]]

positional arguments:
  bar         BAR! FOO! Lorem Ipsum is
              simply dummy text of the
              printing and typesetting
              industry.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message
              and exit
  --foo FOO   FOO! Lorem Ipsum is
              simply dummy text of the
              printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum
              has been the industry's
              standard dummy text ever
              since the 1500s, when an
              u
```

**Code with hardcode 40**

```
def _split_lines(self, text, width):
    text = self._whitespace_matcher.sub(' ', text).strip()
    return _textwrap.wrap(text, 40)
```

**Output**

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo FOO] [bar [bar ...]]

positional arguments:
  bar         BAR! FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
              text of the printing and typesetting
              industry.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
              the printing and typesetting industry.
              Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
              standard dummy text ever since the
```

## PreserveWhiteSpaces and e.g. Bulletpoints

If you want to preserve the whitespace in front of a newline I wrote just a PreserveWhiteSpaceWrapRawTextHelpFormatter.

```
import argparse
import textwrap as _textwrap
import re

class PreserveWhiteSpaceWrapRawTextHelpFormatter(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
    def __add_whitespace(self, idx, iWSpace, text):
        if idx is 0:
            return text
        return (" " * iWSpace) + text

    def _split_lines(self, text, width):
        textRows = text.splitlines()
        for idx,line in enumerate(textRows):
            search = re.search('\s*[0-9\-]{0,}\.?\s*', line)
            if line.strip() is "":
                textRows[idx] = " "
            elif search:
                lWSpace = search.end()
                lines = [self.__add_whitespace(i,lWSpace,x) for i,x in enumerate(_textwrap.wrap(line, width))]
                textRows[idx] = lines

        return [item for sublist in textRows for item in sublist]
```

It just looks whats the indention for text text and add this for each `_textwrap.warp` line. Called with this Arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    prog='PROG',
    formatter_class=PreserveWhiteSpaceWrapRawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--foo', type=int, default=42, help="""Just Normal Bullet Point with Some Enter in there

    1. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    2. the 1500s, when an u
    3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry

Some other Bullet POint

    - Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
    - Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry

And No BulletPoint
    Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
    Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
    """)
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='*', default=[1, 2, 3], help="BAR! FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.")
parser.print_help()
```

**Output**

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo FOO] [bar [bar ...]]

positional arguments:
  bar         BAR! FOO! Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   Just Normal Bullet Point with Some Enter in there

                  1. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                     ever since
                  2. the 1500s, when an u
                  3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                     typesetting industry

              Some other Bullet POint

                  - Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                    industry
                  - Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                    industry

              And No BulletPoint and no Enter
                  Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                  industry
                  Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                  industry
```

Comment: I had the impression that the OP wanted to preserve his own new lines, while still allowing wrapping of long ones.  For example with bullet points or paragraphs.  I don't think the custom width was the primary concern.  But I may be wrong.

Comment: @hpaulj I think your notice and comment is right. Added the section where I wrote a `PreserveWhiteSpaceWrapRawTextHelpFormatter`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! With a few small modifications (enhancements) this works exactly as desired, even better. And @hpaulj was right, the main concern was preserving my own formatting while wrapping the lines automatically.

Comment: In **Python 3.5.2** the usage/help folding to `$COLUMNS` seems automatically implemented with none of the above addictions, **provided you don't use the characters `[` and `]` if you don't want to get a nasty bug**.